# Matlab: what is the best way to reshape a large matrix based on sub-matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a large matrix of *250*-by-*200*. Inside it are *50*-by-*50* smaller *5*-by-*4* matrices.

What is the best way to reshape the matrix so that the 2500 *5*-by-*4* smaller matrices are aligned horizontally to each other? So the large matrix's end dimension should be *5*-by-*10000*.

Comment: When you say 50, do you really mean 50x50 = 2500?

Comment: Yes the large matrix is filled with 50x50 smaller 5x4 matrices.

Comment: Hi Matt I've added some clarification, can you see if you understand the problem?

Comment: in what order should the submatrices be in the output matrix? column-wise or row-wise from the input matrix?

Comment: row-wise. So the first submatrix in the second row gets moved beside the submatrix in the end of the first row.

Comment: I just wanted to bring attention to a more efficient code compared to the accepted answer that [I posted below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31701546/3183836). You do request the _best way_ to reshape this matrix so if that means efficiency is important to you, check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Matlab's `reshape` function is pretty handy (and fast), but always reads and writes *complete* columns. So for your problem, some additional steps are necessary.

Here is how you can do it:

```
m = 5 % columns of submatrix
n = 4 % rows of submatrix
k = 50 % num submatrixes in matrix column
l = 50 % num submatrixes in matrix row
A = rand(m*k,n*l); % rand(250,200)
```

Reshape the matrix into a four dimensional matrix (dimensions x1,x2,x3,x4), where each submatrix is located in the x1-x3 plane. The submatrix columns from the original matrix are then in x2 direction, and the submatrix rows in x4 direction.

```
B = reshape(A,[m,k,n,l]); % [4,50,5,50]
```

Permute ('transpose') the 4D matrix, so that each submatrix is located in the x1-x2 plane. (`reshape` first reads columns, then rows, then 3rd dimension, etc.)

```
C = permute(B,[1,3,4,2]); % For column-wise reshaping, use [1,3,2,4]
```

Reshape the 4D matrix into the desired 2D output matrix.

```
D = reshape(C,m,[]);
```

Comment: `reshape` can be used row-wise when [transposed](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) before.

Comment: My point was more that it reads complete columns, meaning you can't tell it to only read the first 5 entries of a column, and then proceed with the next column. I will clearify it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`mat2cell`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html), then [`reshape`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) and finally get the matrix back with [`cell2mat`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html). For demonstration purposes, I used variables `n` and `m`. They would both be 50 for your matrix.

*The following code does it row-wise as you clarified in your comment:*

```
n = 3;                          % rows
m = 2;                          % columns

A = reshape(1:20,[5,4]);        % generate some data
M = repmat(A,n,m);              % create the large matrix

X = mat2cell(M,repmat(5,1,n),repmat(4,1,m))
X = reshape(X.',1,[])
X = cell2mat(X)
```

**Note:** `reshape` operates column-wise. Therefore we need to transpose `X` with `.'` or [`transpose`](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) before using `reshape` as shown in the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd add another approach that uses indices and one built-in function `zeros`. Maybe this way won't have any unnecessary error checks or reshaping operations. Turns out it's more efficient (see below).

```
%submatrix size
m = 5;
n = 4;
%repeated submatrix rows and cols
rep_rows = 50;
rep_cols = 50;
% big matrix
A = rand(m * rep_rows, n * rep_cols);
% create new matrix 
C = zeros(m, (n * rep_cols) * rep_rows);
for k = 1:rep_rows
   ind_cols = (n * rep_cols) * (k - 1) + 1: (n * rep_cols) * k;
   ind_rows = m * (k - 1) + 1: m * k;
   C(:, ind_cols) = A(ind_rows, :);
end
```

I decided to time the three answers here and found this approach to be significantly faster. Here is the test code:

```
% Bastian's approach
m = 5; % columns of submatrix
n = 4; % rows of submatrix
k = 50; % num submatrixes in matrix column
l = 50; % num submatrixes in matrix row
A = rand(m*k,n*l); % rand(250,200)
% start timing
tic
B = reshape(A,[m,k,n,l]); % [4,50,5,50]
C = permute(B,[1,3,4,2]); % For column-wise reshaping, use [1,3,2,4]
D = reshape(C,m,[]);
toc
% stop timing
disp('                ^^^ Bastian');

% Matt's approach
n = 50;                          % rows
m = 50;                          % columns
% start timing
tic
X = mat2cell(A,repmat(5,1,n),repmat(4,1,m));
X = reshape(X.',1,[]);
X = cell2mat(X);
toc
% stop timing
disp('                ^^^ Matt');

% ChisholmKyle
m = 5;
n = 4;
rep_rows = 50;
rep_cols = 50;
% start timing
tic
C = zeros(m, (n * rep_cols) * rep_rows);
for k = 1:rep_rows
   ind_cols = (n * rep_cols) * (k - 1) + 1: (n * rep_cols) * k;
   ind_rows = m * (k - 1) + 1: m * k;
   C(:,ind_cols) = A(ind_rows, :);
end
toc
% stop timing
disp('                ^^^ this approach');
```

Here is the output on my machine:

```
Elapsed time is 0.004038 seconds.
                ^^^ Bastian
Elapsed time is 0.020217 seconds.
                ^^^ Matt
Elapsed time is 0.000604 seconds.
                ^^^ this approach
```

Comment: Good one! Apparently, loops really became a lot faster over the years =)

Comment: I noticed that my approach is only much slower at the first execution after a `clear all` or `clear functions`. Otherwise, both solutions are roughly as fast. Apparently, my version takes a lot of time for being compiled, but the execution time of the compiled script is pretty fast.

Comment: Gotta love Matlab's Just-In-Time compiler!